# Why does my jQuery/CSS animation only work on first click?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, fade

I'm attempting to make an element fade out and then fade in each time a link is clicked. I have the following code, for some strange reason it only works on first click.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aueLr8k0/3/

```js
$("body").on('click', 'a', function () {
   $("div").removeClass('fade').addClass('fade');
})
```

```css
.fade {
    animation: fadeinout .5s;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click this</a><br><br>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;background:red"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could listen to `animationend` event and remove class on it

```js
$("body").on('click', 'a', function () {
   $("div").addClass('fade').one('animationend', function() {
     $(this).removeClass('fade');
   });
})
```

```css
.fade {
    animation: fadeinout .5s;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click this</a><br><br>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;background:red"></div>
```

Comment: I marked this as the best answer. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: I didn't realized that you can listen for the css animation only ones. I had always the problem to wait for the css animation which was started by adding a class. Finally I found the best solution. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

`$("div").removeClass('fade').addClass('fade');` will execute rather instantaneously and functionally you'll just end up with the `fade` class

Depending on the order in which you want the classes to be applied, you'll likely want to add timeouts to either/or/both `addClass` and `removeClass`

This is an example where the `removeClass` call will execute immediately and the `addClass` will occur after a delay.

```js
$("body").on('click', 'a', function () {
  $("div").addClass('fade')
  setTimeout(function () { $("div").removeClass('fade') }, 1000) // 1000 milliseconds
})
```

```css
.fade {
    animation: fadeinout 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click this</a><br><br>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;background:red"></div>
```

Comment: Depending on the behavior you are looking to obtain you may want to actually add the timeout on `removeClass` so that it fades out after a period of time. Last note is if you have multiple elements like this you may want to replace the general `$('div')` with `$(e.currentTarget)` after passing `e` to the click handler function.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I would rather addClass first then setTimeout to remove it

Comment: Okay @Luvias I edited this per your note -- I also extended the animation and timeout to make it more clear what it's doing. You can tweak the animation and timeout until you get the effect you want.